# Typescript + keyof. Declaring an object transformation

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, keyof

im trying to understand keyof.

I want to describe a function which receives an object `{ a : 1, b : 'anything'}` and should return something like `{ a: true , b: false }` (same keys, but always boolean values).

But when I write (example)

```
function fn<K>(obj:K) : { [param:keyof K] : boolean } { /* ... */ }
```

... TS says me `param` must be string or number.

That makes sense, since K can be a map. How could I avoid that error? How could I declare that K is a plain JS object (so its keys are always string)? `K extends {}` doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
function fn<K>(obj: K): { [P in keyof K]: boolean } { /* ... */ }
```

As shown in the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) section of the [keyof feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).